# Jar files in the Ubuntu Hud

Tags: unity, java, launcher

So I have a few jar files that I frequently use (Minecraft and other launchers, to name a few) and they show up under the "File and Folders" section.  If I open other files that have a similar file path, those ones may get farther down in the list whenever I search for the file through the Hud.

Is there any way to have them treated as applications, so that they show up in that section of the Hud, and then their priority gets increased every time I open them?

Answer (score 0):

In fact jar is not an application.  It can be treated like pdf or docx or smth like that.  In detail, jar is just a set of compiled java classes and some meta information packed into zip archive with jar extension.
Can't say if there is any native way, but try to create a shell script launcher, I guess it should be treated as "normal" executable.